# Why doesn't nmap show SIP ports open for this router?

Tags: networking, router, port, nmap, asterisk

SIP calls on from `demo_bob` to `demo_alice` on Asterisk had no sound, so I opened ports on the  [NetGear WNR1000v2 - N150 Wireless Router](http://www.netgear.com/support/product/WNR1000v2):

```
#   Service Type    Port    IP
1   IP_Phone    6670-6670   192.168.1.254-192.168.1.254
2   sip 5060-5061   192.168.1.2-192.168.1.99
```

Solution.  Fixed.

**However**, ports on localhost:

```
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-06-29 23:44 PDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00034s latency).
Not shown: 992 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
110/tcp  open  pop3
119/tcp  open  nntp
631/tcp  open  ipp
2000/tcp open  cisco-sccp
3306/tcp open  mysql

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
thufir@mordor:~$
```

Ports on the router:

```
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ nmap 192.168.1.1

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-06-29 23:44 PDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.1
Host is up (0.0085s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
23/tcp   open  telnet
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
3333/tcp open  dec-notes
5555/tcp open  freeciv

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.15 seconds
thufir@mordor:~$
```

1. Why doesn't nmap show the ports on the router which I opened up?
2. Can I make nmap show those ports specifically and correctly as open?
3. Is nmap the wrong tool?

Comment: IIRC SIP uses UDP.

Comment: nmap does not scan all ports, by default only the common ones.
While SIP should be considered common, you can be sure and specify the port numbers specifically. And as @DanielB say, SIP uses UDP (mostly)

Comment: well, to add a layer of complexity to the question, I had the sound working for localnet SIP calls, but managed to break it.  Not sure what I did or didn't do to the router.

Comment: @Thufir SIP is tricky with NAT translations, you often need a SIP-aware router to perform the NAT translation or a simple Session Border Controller... Many simple residential/SOHO routers do not have this capability.

Comment: for what it's worth, I got it working again, with sound, with calls in excess of one minute.  Using an onsip account I dialed hello@onsip.com as well.  So that all looks like green lights.  That being said, I should download my router settings and add them here.  (Hopefully I don't have to type them in by hand.)

Comment: @Thufir You may also have to disable [SIP ALG](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Routers+SIP+ALG) on your router as well. "many routers' ALG implementations are wrong and break SIP."

Comment: @DavidPostill  SIP ALG is disabled.